# Capture browser events

Tags: javascript, events, browser

How can i capture the browser events like 'window close', 'back button pressed' using javascript or any other client script.

Is there a way to capture the events when clicked outside the document.

Comment: See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597459/javascript-cookie-expiration-deletion-on-different-browsing-scenarios/3597507#3597507

Comment: Can I use browsers code inside my webpage like 
for example:
 In chrome : there are codes like chrome.tabs.onclosed, chrome.tabs.onUpdated.

Is it possible use such code in my webpage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *unload* and *beforeunload* events will fire when the window is closed or the back button is pressed, but they will also fire for any type of navigation away from the current page.

You can't capture events outside the context of your web page.